# How to choose terms to sum in a series in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

```
m = int(raw_input());


def objective(x):  # Definining minimization function
# in function range(1,m) 1 is included and m is excluded. So effectively we go from 1 to m-1.
        first = 0.0
        second = 0.0

        for j in range(1, m):
            term_1 = 1.0
            term_2 = 0.0
            for i in range(1,m):
                term_1 -= 2*(x[i]*math.pow(math.sin(pi*i*j/m),2))
                term_2 += ((x[i])*i* math.sin(2*pi*i*j/m))



            first = first + math.pow(term_1, 2)
            second = second + math.pow(term_2, 2)

        Fmin = first + second
        return Fmin
        asum = 0.0
        for i in range (1,m):
            asum = asum - x[i]
```

So I'm trying to sum terms in a cosine series in python 2.7.12. Say I want to sum the 1st, 3rd, and 5th term, but not the second or 4th. Is there a way to specify that in a for loop? I'd want to be able to change which terms I refrain from summing if possible. This is the part of my script that defines what I'm summing over. I'm optimizing this function later on in the script, but I want to be able to fix certain terms to 0. As it stands, It's just summing all of i and j

Comment: Of course there is a way. Show us what you already tried and we'll be able to help you from there.

Comment: Have a list of indices you want to sum and iterate over them.

Comment: `sum(terms[::2])`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you can use something like:

```
sum([value for index, value in enumerate(data) if index % 2 != 0])
```